Can we have more relevant options to the "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" close reason?
Currently the only option available in the "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" menu is chinese.meta.stackexchange.com.
That's definitely not exhaustive. Other items in that menu that would make sense are:

japanese.stackexchange.com: rather easy for newbies to confuse Japanese with Chinese.
linguistics.stackexchange.com: even though we have a [linguistics] tag, its purpose is basically to restrict the scope of terminology questions, or for questions about Chinese but with highly technical content.
buddhism.stackexchange.com
travel.stackexchange.com
anything else?


That aside, following this thread Can we have a “Not about the Chinese language” close reason? a clarification is needed.
If the "not about Chinese" close reason is approved, when would you choose that over "belongs to another site in SE"?
In short, the answer to that is: you choose "Not about Chinese" over "belongs to another site" when the question would be off-topic on that other site, i.e. no migration would be possible. Remember that marking a question as "belongs to another site" in practice means "mods should migrate this question over there". If the question would be off-topic over there, then it doesn't actually belong there, and "Not about Chinese", or another applicable close reason, should be chosen instead. Or when the site it would be on-topic on isn't in the list.

The site I'd like on this list is Language Learning (see also Alternative Stack Exchange sites for "not really about the Chinese language" questions).  To my knowledge, changing the “belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network” list, we need to get Stack Exchange staff involved; diamond mods cannot do this:

We're still going to look at what has been sent to a destination (mostly by mods) and look at the rejection rate before we set up a migration path. That's still pretty much data-driven.
Grace Note, Meta.SE, 2015

The general attitude I've encountered when reading about this on meta sites is that changing the "belongs on another site" list is almost never necessary:

Diamond mods can already migrate questions.
Migration is rarely necessary: the author can just re-ask their question on the other site (and maybe ask a better question).
There are risks of migrating a question to a site where it is off-topic (users here do not necessarily understand what's on/off-topic elsewhere).

I suspect it's simply not worth the effort pursuing this.  At least not until migration-worthy questions become more frequent.

I should also note that just because something is on-topic at site A, doesn't mean it's off-topic at site B (e.g. Star Wars is on topic at both Movies and SciFi; there's an Ubuntu site despite Ubuntu being on topic at Unix).  This is often not obvious.
